50's or 60's movie with man and boy and woman, living in a cabin
I'm trying to find the title of an old movie for which I can only remember a couple scenes from.
It would be a 50's to 60's  color movie, era of Seven brides for seven brothers. (I don't believe it was a musical, but I reference that as a comparable filming technology level movie.)
Setting: A man, and a boy of late teens age (possibly his son) are living in a cabin in the woods in "the west" (mountains and pine trees west, not arid desert west).
Through some set of circumstances, a woman of no relation to them ends up living with them in this cabin. She's of approximate age for a romantic interest between her and the man to be reasonable, though I don't remember if the movie goes that route, as it doesn't start that way, nor is that yet the situation during which the scenes I remember take place. (I'd suspect it goes that route though, since we are talking about a 50's Hollywood movie.)
Remembered scene 1: Teenage boy + woman in the cabin. Man is not present.
The boy is trying to dry his hair just by ruffling it with his hands, the woman laughs and says he won't get it dry like that. She brings a towel over and proceeds to dry his hair. The boy turns and kisses her on the lips, expressing a crush he has developed on her, but by her reaction instantly recognizes it was a mistake. He makes her promise not to tell the man (his father?).
-=- Unknown number of interim scenes take place. -=-
Remembered scene 2: The man and woman in the cabin, teenage boy is elsewhere but nearby.
The man and woman are talking, and the man laughs heartily at something the woman says, just as the boy walks in the door to the cabin.
The boy instantly assumes that they're having a laugh at his expense, for the mistaken kiss earlier, and blurts out at the woman: "You promised you wouldn't tell him! You said you wouldn't tell I kissed you!" (Or something to that effect, both accusing her of revealing the event, while also describing it.)
The man's mood changes to a serious one, and the woman apologetically denies breaking the confidence (which is true, she had not), saying "But I didn't tell him what happened!" The man turns to the boy and points out "But you just did."
-=-=-=-=-=-
Thanks all for any help! This one has been bugging me for a bit, as it's been years since I saw this, and I don't even remember if I saw the whole movie at the time.

This vaguely reminds me of River of No Return  (1954) with Robert Mitchum, Marilyn Monroe, Rory Calhoun, and Tommy Rettig, but I don't remember those specific scenes. 

Hmm, I do know that I've seen River of No Return before, but it's been a long time for that one as well. I'll see if I can pick that up from the library and check for these scenes.
